# Font resize with cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies

Trying to create some website options where users can select their own font size, and I want that font size to maintain throughout the site on different pages etc. The font changer works fine but I'm having troubles with the cookies (1st time using them!)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var Cookie = "Font Size";
var fontsize = normal;

if($.cookie(Cookie)) {
    fontsize = $.cookie(Cookie);
    if (fontsize == "normal") {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "12px"});
    }
    else if (fontsize == "larger") {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "14px"});
    }
    else {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "16px"});
    }
} 
else {
    $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
}
} 

function normalFont() {
$("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "12px"});
fontsize = normal;
$.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
}

 function largerFont() {
$("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "14px"});
fontsize = larger;
$.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
 }
 function biggestFont() {
$("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({"font-size": "16px"});
fontsize = biggest;
$.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
 }
```

HTML:
I'm using buttons with onclick="normalFont() etc

Also have downloaded the Jquery cookie plugin and linked it in

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: syntax error in `var fontsize = normal;`, it should be `var fontsize = 'normal';` the string literal `normal` should be enclosed within `''` or `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple syntax errors

```
//this should be in global scope
var Cookie = "Font Size";
$(document).ready(function () {

    //string literal
    //also read the cookie value, if it is not present use the default value as `normal`
    var fontsize = $.cookie(Cookie) || 'normal';

    if (fontsize == "normal") {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
            "font-size": "12px"
        });
    } else if (fontsize == "larger") {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
            "font-size": "14px"
        });
    } else {
        $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
            "font-size": "16px"
        });
    }
}); //missing ) here

function normalFont() {
    $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
    //string literal
    fontsize = 'normal';
    $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
}

function largerFont() {
    $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
        "font-size": "14px"
    });
    //string literal
    fontsize = 'larger';
    $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
}

function biggestFont() {
    $("#main p, #side p, #box p, .header li").css({
        "font-size": "16px"
    });
    //string literal
    fontsize = 'biggest';
    $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tB6cL/)

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes

```
var fontsize = "normal";
```

and

```
fontsize = "larger";
```

and

```
fontsize = "biggest";
```